# Angularjs: nicer way to handle circular dependencies

Tags: angularjs, circular-dependency

Is there another way how to handle circular dependencies in Angular service than by using `$injector.get()`?

Is `require.js` the right choice?

Comment: Why not refactor so you don't have circular dependencies?

Comment: As it is not always possible to keep the code nicely readable and structured.

Comment: No, there's no way. Yes, it's the right choice.

Comment: @estus Sorry, estus, I don't what is your NO and YES for...

Comment: I am trying to get rid off the circular deps. It really separates concerns more.

Comment: @JoeyCiechanowicz Please have a look at my answer. Maybe you can give me a better advice. Thx.

Comment: @estus I have just realized what you meant with your comment. Thx.

Comment: Sometimes circular depencies just happen, for instance if you want to configure an $http interceptor and use ui-router to redirect, you will have a circular dependency. Just use $injector.get(). You just need to be carefull that it happen only when you really need it.

Comment: @Walfrat I do agree. By now I could really remove all `$injector.get()` by separating concerns better.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Tip:** *Never inject anything except other models into your models or you end up with circular dependencies.*